Bcrypt compare mocking issue for unit testing in Nestjs
This is my authService code and i am trying to unit test with vitest this block
  async validateUser(
    email: string,
    password: string,
  ): Promise<User | UserToSetupAccountDto | null> {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email },
    });

    if (!user || !user.password) {
      const isTemporaryPasswordValid = await this.validateTemporaryPassword(
        email,
        password,
      );

      if (isTemporaryPasswordValid) {
        if (user) {
          return user;
        }

        return { email, forceUserToSetupAccount: true };
      }

      return null;
    }

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isMatch) {
      return null;
    }

    return user;
  }

and I wrote this test with vitest but
AssertionError: expected "compare" to be called with arguments: [ 'wrongPassword', 'hashedPassword' ]
I'm getting this error
it('Should return null if user exist and compare false', async () => {
 const mockUser = { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'hashedPassword', };
  mockPrismaService.user.findUnique.mockResolvedValue(mockUser);

  const mockBcrypt = vi.spyOn(bcrypt, 'compare').mockResolvedValue(false);
  const result = await authService.validateUser(
    mockUser.email,
    'wrongPassword',
  );
  expect(bcrypt.compare).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    'wrongPassword',
    mockUser.password,
  );
  expect(result).toBe(null);


});


Is the expect toHaveBeenCalledWith call supposed to be before  the await authService.validateUser? Normally, you state what you "expect" will happen as part of preparation, then you perform the test. At the end of the test, the framework checks that the expectations were met.

Actually, the expect statement needs to be placed after the await authService.validateUser call because we can't check our expectations before the bcrypt.compare function inside the validateUser method is called.

I fixed my problem if you have same problem you can visit link <- YogeshUmeshVaity's github
